# Hyperledger Fabric : Strategies for Storing Private-Public Keys on a Mobile phone

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have a Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 Application. On the Desktop Client Application, I am using the traditional Filesystem Strategy for Storing the Identities (Private and Public Keys).

Now I need a mobile client to connect to the system. In this case what would be a good strategy to store the Identities? Does the Fabric Node SDK provide any methods for mobile-specific use cases?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.